# How to run Android app using TeamCity when there is PR on API repo?

Tags: android, api, continuous-integration, teamcity

How to run Android test app automatically using TeamCity when there is Pull Request from develop to master branch on API repository?

I have TeamCity connected to GitHub using account with reader permissions.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure `VCS Trigger` for this. 
Assuming you have already configured project in TC, go to project's build configuration then go to `Triggers` section and add a new one.

[image]

[image]

That triggers build on each commit to the repository. Branch filtering should be helpful for you if you are looking only for automatic builds when merging to master.

More information about this TC feature can be found in [docs](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Configuring+VCS+Triggers).

Hope that helps.

Comment: So VCS Trigger can be from different repo rather than repo of the actual build? I can't see Branch filter option even if there are different branches.

Comment: Hmm .. never tried this way, but maybe adding another VSC will do the trick. You don't see branch filtering option? What version of TC are you using?

Comment: latest one TeamCity-2018.2.1